# Getting random number sequence on a filename using rename on Linux

Tags: bash, perl, file-rename

So I'm trying to mass rename folder full of JPG-files using the 'rename'-tool

End result should be looking something like this

```
745I-24814
745I-(five random numbers)
```

I need something that gives me those five random numbers, the rest works fine

```
rename -n  's/\w+/745I\- [stuff] /' *.jpg
```

Most things just, like those two, act as strings instead of code or give gibberish

```
'int(rand(1000))+1000'
$(( ( RANDOM % 1000) + 1000))
```

Comment: Not sure why this one was downvoted. All effort is shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `rename` uses a Perl substitution, to execute code in the replacement, you need `/e`:

```
s/\w+/10000 + int rand 90000/e
```

Comment: or to match what was asked for, `s/\w+/"745I-" . ( 10000 + int rand 90000 )/e` (untested)

Comment: note that for more than just a few files, you risk getting duplicate random numbers; with 43 files you have a 1% chance; with 909 files, you have a 99% chance of at least one duplicate